# How can I murder with a No Crime morality follower without them turning against me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on the PS3, and I have Uthgerd the Unbroken following me, who will attack me if I commit crimes against residents of Whiterun. Is there a way I can kill people without her attacking me? Because I really want Nazeem and the Talos preacher guy dead, but I don't want to have to either kill Uthgerd, or make her go home every time I want to murder someone.

Comment: bucket on head.

Comment: come on, give Heimskr a break, sure he can get annoying with his preaching of Talos but he isn't a Thalmor boot licker like everyone else.

Comment: Nazeem on the other hand yeh, give that pretentious b****** a good arrow to the knee/knife in the back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uthgerd will only turn on you if you're caught committing a crime (gain bounty). It's not a problem if Uthgerd witnesses it as long as it's not detected (seen/heard) by other NPCs. Here are a few things you can try:

- A frenzy spell does the trick for me.  Once they're frenzied you can kill them in view of everyone or let other NPCs do it for you. Spell casting is silent with quiet casting (illusion perk).
- Knife them in their sleep. Dagger attacks are silent.
- Bow sneak attacks work but are not silent like the above methods.

I've tested all this in game to confirm that Uthgerd does not go hostile. Good hunting.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your follower to wait in a location(breezehome). Kill Heimskr, get rid of your bounty, and ask your follower to follow you again.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Heimskr is the Talos priest in Whiterun.